# rjags: error in node x, node inconsistent with parents - Logistic regression 'Liszt-package' in R 4.0.0

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, rjags

I am trying to perform a listlength-analysis (basically a multiple logistic regression) in a Bayesian framework using the 'Liszt' package. This is a beta package that can only be installed from here: 
http://www.possinghamlab.org/images/LLA/Liszt_0.8-5_1.tar.gz

When i look into the package, the model for rjags is as follows:

```
A3ModelFun <-
function(Species, Year, ListLength = rowSums(Species), sp.names = colnames(Species),
                           midYear = round(median(unique(Year))),
                           n.iter=50000, n.burnin=20000,
                           resultFolder = NULL) {

.folder <-
    function(tag = "ListLengthAnalysis") {
      paste(gsub("[^0-9]", "_", as.character(strptime(date(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))), tag, sep="_")
    }

#checks
#Will not work if all the years aren't supplied
       if(length(Year) != nrow(Species)) { 
           stop("Number of years supplied not equal to number of lists") }              

#When there is only one species the analysis wont run ... 
      if(length(Species) == 1) {
        stop("Only one species") }

  #Assign default folder name if unspecified
  if(is.null(resultFolder)) resultFolder <- .folder()
  is.folder <- function(file) file.info(file)$isdir
  if(is.na(is.folder(resultFolder))) dir.create(resultFolder) else print("folder exists") 

## Set up a folder for the results     

#      if(file.exists(resultFolder))
#        if(!is.folder(resultFolder)) stop("File ", resultFolder, " exists and is not a folder") else
#          dir.create(resultFolder)

  #Assign default midYear if unspecified
  if(is.null(midYear)) midYear <- round(median(unique(Year)))

      ## Create a function to generate inits (outside the for loop as it is the same params for every model)
      inits <- function() list(a1=rnorm(1), a2=rnorm(1), a3=rnorm(1))

      ModelFile <- tempfile()
      LL <- ListLength
      no <- nrow(Species)                       ## need to set these
      my <- midYear
      nyear <- length(unique(Year))
      meanLogLL <- mean(log(ListLength))
      halfyr <- nyear/2


##Progress Report
      j <- 1
      tot <- length(sp.names)
      for (i in sp.names) {
        cat(i, "\n")
        cat(j, "out of", tot, "\n")
        j <- j+1
      }

#####List Length Analysis#####        
      for (i in sp.names) {  # changed this from for (i in sp.names[]) { & for (i in sp.names[i])

        ## Define data for each model (we can reuse this object for each model)
        LLAData.1sp <- list(pres=Species[, i], yr=Year, LL=ListLength)

        ## Define the JAGS model
        cat(sprintf('
                    model {               
                    for (i in 1:%s) {
                    pres[i] ~ dbern(p[i])
                    logit(p[i]) <- a1 +
                    a2 * (log(LL[i]) - %s) +
                    a3 * (yr[i] - %s)            
                    }

                    a1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
                    a2 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
                    a3 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)


                    }', no, meanLogLL, my, my),
              file=ModelFile)

    ## Run a model and store it in an R object called model_spname (where spname changes with each model)
    assign(sprintf('model_%s', i),
           jags(LLAData.1sp, inits,
                parameters.to.save=c(
                  'a1', 'a2', 'a3'),
                n.iter=n.iter, n.burnin=n.burnin, ModelFile))

    ## Save the current model to a file with the same names
    save(list=sprintf('model_%s', i), file=file.path(resultFolder, sprintf('model_%s.RData', i)))

    ## Delete the current model to save space
    rm(list = sprintf('model_%s', i))
}

  file.remove(ModelFile)
  return(resultFolder)
  }
```

There is a lot of irrelevant stuff for the model itself, but i feel it is better to place the whole piece of code.

When i run it with my data, i always get the error:

```
Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  Error in node pres[5]
Node inconsistent with parents
```

I found that more people had this error message, but it always had to do with the data in relation to the distribution used (i.e. negative data for gamma distribution, poisson for binomial). I have binomial distributed data, but still get the error. I can't figure out why.

My model is as follows (see dput below for a 20 row subsample of my dataframe, i get the same error only on different node with complete dataset):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- (dput)
sp.ll <-as.matrix(df %>% select(-Year, -Hok_uniek, -LL))

mod <- A3ModelFun(sp.ll, df$Year, df$LL)
```

Data (on drive, because otherwise i will exceed the max amount of characters):

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1etj_7IrEHJbYzBk9p_8tW6B-X0HpbLU9WMWMJL-QT_I

Comment: In my experience, when having issues with packages that are not yet used by many, contacting the developers directly is a productive course of action. I realise that this is a very generic advice.

Comment: Thanks Marco, this crossed my mind but i wanted to try it here first. I have had some very helpfull comments on the 'R for ecology' Facebook-page. Someone suggested that the ini values should not be specified and that jagsUI is a better choice than R2jags. I did a very little testrun and everything seems to work. When this adjustment to the model fails on the large dataset, i will contact the developers. Regards